# How do I make the VPN use different DNS?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I want to connect to a other computer (computers that I don't manage at my university) via VPN. I wanna use the default Ubuntu way of doing that (no openVPN). After getting succesfully connected to VPN I need to use ssh to connect with computer in the uni local network. But I have problem, when I do:

```
ssh sth@lab109-01.stud.ii
```

I get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname lab109-01.stud.ii: Name or service not known
```

`lab109-01` is lab and computer ids so it will change depending on what computer I wanna use. It's just one host, one computer, I have many many to choose from and I will. So using `/etc/hosts` is not really great here.

So DNS don't know that host. I tried using uni DNS servers which worked, but when I wasn't using VPN everything was really slow. I also want to avoid having to change settings (DNS servers) all the time.

[image: Here you can see vpn settings (GUI)]

In Ubuntu 20.04 in that VPN settings I disabled `Automatic` for DNS and filled input with uni DNS servers ips. But it doesn't work.

I've tried many things to get it work. Downgrading network-manager is said to work but it'd have to be downgraded to v10 and I have installed v20 so it's rather a big difference so I'm not sure about that.
How do I use different DNS servers for just that VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add 'lab109-01.stud.ii' with ip address in /etc/hosts file?

Comment: It's just one host, one computer, I have many many to choose from and I will. So using /etc/hosts is not really great here.

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

In the VPN settings leave `Use this connection only for resources on its network` unchecked.
Now VPN uses DNS servers provided for it but for connections other than that VPN globally set VPN servers are used, command `resolvectl dns` conforms that.